# Place "SHARE" button in the vertical & horizontal center of an image (when onhover fires)

Tags: html, css, share, center

A good example of what I'm trying to do is Fancy: http://www.fancy.com/
If you hover over an image of a post, the background gets dark (to a percentage) and a button appears in the front.

I want to do the same but with a SHARE button. I place the image as an img and the SHARE button as a background. However, I cannot figure out how to darken the image without darkening the SHARE button as well.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="src">
<img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

My CSS Code:

```
div.src{
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background:url('icon-share.png') center center no-repeat;
    opacity: 1;
}
div.src img{
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 200px;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Can you help?

The width is always 500px but the height is variable (min-height of 200px). I'd also like to darken the image instead of applying opacity but that's not a hard problem I think.

EDIT: Of course clicking on the entire image will open the share dialogue. The floating SHARE button is just to inform the user that he's going to share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we're talking pure html and css, you could insert another `<div>` or even an `<a>` inside the image holder above the image.

```
a.share {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:url(path to icon) rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
}
```

Comment: I've placed it before the <img />. The problem with your solution is that the width:100%; height:100%; don't get the "correct value", instead they take up the whole page!

Comment: Okay, I got it working. I needed to add "position: relative;" to the src div.